# Why does template parameter deduction fail when calling the constructor like this?

Tags: c++, templates

The following won't compile:

```
struct S {
    template <class T> S(T) {}
};
void f(int) {}
int main() {
    S(f);
}
```

g++-4.9 says

```
template.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
template.cpp:6:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘S::S()’
     S(f);
        ^
template.cpp:6:8: note: candidates are:
template.cpp:2:24: note: template<class T> S::S(T)
     template <class T> S(T) {}
                        ^
template.cpp:2:24: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
template.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
     S(f);
        ^
template.cpp:1:8: note: constexpr S::S(const S&)
 struct S {
        ^
template.cpp:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
template.cpp:1:8: note: constexpr S::S(S&&)
template.cpp:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

clang gives a similar error.

On the other hand, the following compiles:

```
struct S {
    template <class T> S(T) {}
};
void f(int) {}
int main() {
    S s = S(f); // this line was changed
}
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

The code you've written doesn't mean what you think it is, you are actually declaring a variable of type `S` having the name `f`; it is **not** constructing an unnamed entity of type `S`, with `f` as argument.

<sup>**Note:** When you change the line into `S s = S(f)` you are however declaring a variable named `s` of type `S`, initialized with a temporary `S(f)` (ie. the *copy-constructor* of *S*  will be used to initialize `s`).</sup>

---

**THE SOLUTION**

Wrap the type in parenthesis, or use *uniform-initialization* (which was introduced in C++11).

```
(S) (f); // creates a temporary of type S initialized with `f`
```

```
S { f }; // c++11
```

---

**THE REASON**

The standard ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) says that `T(x)` is equivalent to `T x` when declaring a variable, as can be read in the below section:

> 8.3p6 **Meaning of declarators** `[dcl.meaning]`
>
> > In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
> >
> > ```
> > ( D1 )
> > ```
> >
> > the type of the contained declarator-id is the same as of the
> >     contained *declarator-id*  in the declaration
> >
> > ```
> > T D1
> > ```
> >
> > Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but
> >     they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

Answer (score 0):

With your definition of struct `S`

```
int main() {

    S(f);                                            //  1 <-----+
    S s(f);           //  2 <-------+                //          +---- SAME
    S s1 ;            //            +---- SAME       //  3 <-----+
    S s2 = S(f) ;     //  4 <-------+

}
```

- 1 & 3 Declares a variable `f` & `s1` respectively of type `S` requires a constructor for initialization
- 2 & 4 construct a variable `s` & `s2` respectively of type `S` using copy constructor (note here the `f` is not your function name)